# What is the correct site for quaternion and rotation questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

There are many Stack Exchange sites where a question of this type could fit. I can think of:

- [Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)
- Stack Overflow.

To explain my question I would use [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)), although the question is not related to Unity, but to rotations. What would be the Stack Exchange site in this case? And if Unity was not involved at all?

Small description of the question, as the question is a bit dense. I achieve an angle of rotation in a determined way with unity. I would like to know if there is a better approach for that operation. Presumably if there is, the approach involved has to do more with quaternion understanding than with unity itself.

Apart from my concrete question, I was thinking if rotation related questions could have a preferential Stack Exchange site, when programming or Unity are not involved.

Comment: Stack Overflow would only be suiteable when you have a programming problem with quaternions. If you need help with the mathematical/theoretical aspect, it's very likely off-topic on SO.

Comment: If you need help on the mathematical aspects, then of course se.math seems the good site. A good strategy is to go on these sites and to make a search with [quaternion] flag, and to look for similar questions as yours.

Comment: Possibly because more information on what your question is would be helpful. Maybe add a short description to see if it's programming-related or pure mathematics etc.?

Comment: Asking where a hypothetical poorly-defined question is on-topic is not that useful, since there are a lot of if-thens. Best just write the full question, and provide it at the end, to make the problem really specific.

Comment: Question itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64135470/euler-angles-for-a-direction-respect-to-rotated-local-axis-system-in-unity. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: "Unity" is [a heavily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)) [overloaded term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Enterprise_Library#Version_5.0_Silverlight_Integration_Pack).

Comment: This is an interesting question. I wonder: would this have been actually two questions? When I was playing around with 3D game development stuff my questions were always solved in two stages. How to math it, and then how to practically implement it. Are you sure you understood enough about the theory behind this to be able to ask a question about the practical implementation? Given the difficulty of how your question started up... maybe not?

Comment: My point was to know exactly where the rotatition and quaternion questions fit best, but this came up due to a specific issue I was having. I guess I got it a bit mixed up. It seems that pure quaternion or rotation topics fit best in the math stack exchange. Although rotation involve movement, so may make you think that is dynamics related, it is much more related to matrix transformations and algebra, so maths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on exactly what aspect of that you're asking about, and what kind of answer you're looking for.

The comments already pointed this out, but if you're having a programming problem, Stack Overflow is good. If you're having a problem with the math, Math.se would be good.

Physics would probably be at a slightly higher level than quaternions themselves. You'd probably have to be asking about something about one of the "physical" aspects of the rotation itself, not purely about the underlying mathematics.

I'm not quite as familiar with Computer Graphics or Game Development, so I can't offer much advice there. My guess would be that they'd also be higher level than just a "purely" mathematical question (it would have to be a question specific to computer graphics or game development), but since I'm not familiar with those sites you should take that with a grain of salt.

In general, if a question is on-topic at several sites, you should ask yourself what kind of answer you're looking for (and what kind of answer you're looking for). For example, Stack Overflow will probably focus on the programming aspects of this, whereas Math.se would focus primarily on the underlying mathematics. So, if the question is on-topic on both, which one you post on would depend on which aspect you want information on the most.

Sometimes it's possible to ask about one aspect of a problem on one site and another aspect of the question on the other site. (I actually did this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370674/how-to-generalize-my-algorithm-to-detect-if-one-string-is-a-rotation-of-another); I was trying to write an algorithm based on a mathematical "insight" that ended up being wrong. I asked about the supposed insight on Math.se and posted a follow-up on Stack Overflow asking how to salvage my code once Math.se pointed out my mistake).

FWIW, there's also a [relevant Q&A](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/how-to-decide-where-to-post-questions-that-are-on-topic-for-multiple-sites) about a similar issue on Literature Meta about trying to decide where to post a question that's on-topic on several sites.

Comment: this is the question itself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64135470/euler-angles-for-a-direction-respect-to-rotated-local-axis-system-in-unity. Seem it would fit fine either in SO or Game development, due to it relation with unity. As you point out, each part might be disgregatid to the coresponding stack exchange. Also I find that quaternion and rotation pure question fit better in the math than the Physics stack. thanks, regards